# dynamic route for http-request in total.js flow

Tags: node.js, dataflow, total.js

How to use dynamic url for http-request in total.js flow. I am able to get params from route component but how to pass this to http-request url ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible and it's very easy. You can use `Code` (better) or `Repository` component.

- add **`Code`** component with this code:

```
// This will be as dynamic argument stored in hidden Flow Message repository:
repository.code = 'sk';

// or you can bind value from received data:
repository.code = value.code; // value === received data

// Continue with processing
send(0, value);
```

- now you can update URL address in HTTP Request component like this:

```
URL: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/{code}
```

**HTTP Request** component will replace `{code}` for `repository.code` value. You can use multiple values. That's all :-)

Comment: But as i am understanding from repository.code = 'sk';  code will be always sk. I need something repository.code = flowdata.data.params.id  an its a simple param pass. Do we need to store in repository ? @peter-sirka

Comment: I have updated answer. Read carefully info in "Code" component, here is https://github.com/totaljs/flowcomponents/tree/master/code  ... You can bind a value from message easily via "value.YOUR_KEY".